# Sending and receiving info through camera intent

Tags: android

I want to take a picture by opening the camera app using intent. I know how to do that. The problem is that the image comes onActivityResult call. Is there a way I persist a data such as ID so that when I receive the image on activity result, I can use the ID to (say store image path and ID in db). If  I pass data to the camera intent, will get it back in the intent?

I know one approach is to have class variable and store it there but  I have feeling this is prone for errors

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I pass data to the camera intent, will get it back in the intent?

No.

> I know one approach is to have class variable and store it there but I have feeling this is prone for errors

If by "class variable", you mean a field on your activity or fragment, that is the appropriate approach. However, since there is a chance that your process will be terminated while the camera app is in the foreground, you need to hold onto that information in the saved instance state `Bundle`, so you get it back if your activity or fragment gets re-created. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.11/Camera/FileProvider) demonstrates the technique.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the sample